# Why is : $ H^p ( X ( \mathbb{C} ) , \mathbb{Q} ) = \mathrm{Hom}_{ D^b ( \mathrm{pt} ) } ( \mathbb{Q} , ( a_X )_* \mathbb{Q}_X [p] ) $?

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, derived-categories, projective-varieties

There is a paragraph on page $ 133 $ appearing in the following link : https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~peters/Books/Motieven/PureMotives-final.pdf that i don't understand.

The paragraph says :

Recall that if $ X $ is defined over $ \mathbb{C} $ and

$$ a_X \ : \ X \to \mathrm{Spec} \mathbb{C} $$

is the structure morphism, the Betti cohomology $ H^p ( X ( \mathbb{C} ) , \mathbb{Q} ) $ is given by :
$$ H^p ( X ( \mathbb{C} ) , \mathbb{Q} ) = \mathrm{Hom}_{ D^b ( \mathrm{pt} ) } ( \mathbb{Q} , ( a_X )_* \mathbb{Q}_X [p] ) $$

- ***Question*** :

How to show that : 
$$ H^p ( X ( \mathbb{C} ) , \mathbb{Q} ) = \mathrm{Hom}_{ D^b ( \mathrm{pt} ) } ( \mathbb{Q} , ( a_X )_* \mathbb{Q}_X [p] ) $$
?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe I am overlooking something, but I feel like the statement is wrong: If $X=\Bbb{P}^1_{\Bbb{C}}$, then, since $X$ is irreducibe, every locally constant sheaf is actually constant. In particular $\Bbb{Q}$ is flasque, and has no higher cohomology. This implies that the right hand side is $0$ for $p>0$, but of course the left hand side is $Bbb{Q}$ for $p=2$.

Comment: I assume that by $(a_X)_*$, you mean the right derived functor of the direct image. Then since this functor is left adjoint to $a_X^{-1}$ and that $a_X^{-1}\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Q}_X$, you have $$\operatorname{Hom}_{D^b(\operatorname{pt})}(\mathbb{Q},(a_X)_*\mathbb{Q}_X[p])=\operatorname{Hom}_{D^b(X(\mathbb{C}))}(\mathbb{Q}_X,\mathbb{Q}_X[p])=\operatorname{Ext}^p(\mathbb{Q}_X,\mathbb{Q}_X)=H^p(X(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Q})$$

Comment: @Roland : Thank you, but why is : $ H^p ( X ( \mathbb{C} ) , \mathbb{Q} ) = \mathrm{Ext}^p ( \mathbb{Q}_X , \mathbb{Q}_X ) $ ?

Comment: Because there is an obvious isomorphism of functor $\operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}_X,.)\simeq \Gamma(X(\mathcal{C}),.)$ so their $p$-th derived functor are also isomorphic.

Comment: @Roland : Ok. Thank you.  :-)